# Listview showing null when value is not null

Tags: flutter

I think this is a issue with my FutureBuilder/ListView builder. I am displaying a list of events read from SQflite. The event has a nullable organisation name. I am checking for this, and if null, to display 'this is null'

For some of the events ***this is null*** displays despite the value not being null. If I use than bang operator on the field, it always shows as expected. I know at the moment all events have an organisation name, but in the future they may not.

If I scroll the listview down so the event is off screen, and then scroll back up, it usually updates and shows the organisation name.

```
class _EventsListState extends State<EventsList> {
  List<Event>? events;

  late final Future<List<Event>> myFuture = fetchEvents(categoryId: widget.categoryId);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
            FutureBuilder (                
                future: myFuture,
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Event>> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return  Text(snapshot.error.toString());
                  }

                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }

                  return Expanded(
                    child:
                    ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: (snapshot.data == null) ? 0 : snapshot.data!.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {
                          return                           
                            EventTile(event: snapshot.data![position]);
                        }
                    ),
                  );
                }
            ),
        ],
    ),
    );
  }
```

The EventTile showing the organisation like this.

```
Text(widget.event.organisation?.name ?? 'this is null'),
```

Comment: Could you provide the code for `EventTile`?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the structure of your `Event` model class.

I'll suggest making the fields nullable so that in the case it returns null, it uses some placeholder value instead of throwing a stack trace or a null error. Also, that way, you don't have to check the `snapshot.data` is null.

```dart
class Event {
  final String? title;
  final Organisation? organization;
  final String? description;
  final String? imageUrl;

  Event({required this.title, required this.description, required this.imageUrl, required this.organization});

  factory Event.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Event(
      title: json['title'] ?? 'No title',
      description: json['description'] ?? 'No description',
      organization: Organization.fromJson(json['organization']) ?? 
      Organization(name: 'No name'),
      imageUrl: json['imageUrl'] ?? 'https://via.placeholder.com/150',
    );
  }

}
```

You can also make the `fetchEvents()` function return a nullable `List<Event>?`.

Comment: Thanks, but not all of the event returned is showing as null. The event name and image are present, it is just the organisation name (which isn't actually null anyway) - just being reported as such, until the list view is scrolled..

Comment: If it reports the `organisation` instance as null, then there has to be somewhere the value is null. I'll try making the `Organization? organisation` nullable and each fields to see where the issue is coming from.